# How do I get a quantity of two input fields?

Tags: php, post

How can I send the data from these two fields and print a datute in the following way?

```
The way to print:
Color 1, Quantity 6
Color 2, Quantity 1
Color 3, Quantity 1
Color 4, Quantity 1
```

There may be another method, but I personally took a look at this, because by choosing a color, the jQuery field opens the quantity field. If it is not selected, it is hidden.
Thanks !

// I send data with this code:

```
    // ### from here i need to take product id ### 
    <input type="checkbox" name="qty['.$getColorTitle['uniqueID'].']" class="css-checkbox pColor" value="" id="cb-'.$getColorTitle['uniqueID'].'" />
    // ### ### ###

    <label for="cb-'.$getColorTitle['uniqueID'].'">
        <img src="'.$colorFolder.''.$rowColors['image'].'" height="50px" />
        <div class="colorsC">
            // ### from here i need to take quantity ### 
            <input type="hidden" name="qty['.$getColorTitle['uniqueID'].']" value="0" style="width: 45px;" class="qtyC" />
           // ### ### ###
        </div>
    </label>
```

// I taka data with this code:

```
    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    switch($_POST['action']) {
        case 'C':
            foreach($_POST['qty'] as $color_id=>$quantity) {
                if($quantity > 0) {
                    $_SESSION['cart'][$_POST['product_id']][$color_id] = $quantity;
                } else {
                    unset($_SESSION['cart'][$_POST['product_id']][$color_id]);
                }
            }
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: A single-case switch block is more simply write as an if block.  Beyond that, I have no idea what you are asking.  I think you have shown the desired output, but no sample input.

Comment: @mickmackusa 
Hello! I write data for the given color by removing "value" from the field "qty". But now I have a second field that appears or hidden in an active checkbook. How do I take the value of it and write it as an amount of that color?

Comment: you have to set the `value="..."`

Comment: @4givN 
Yes, that's clear. How to set it from the `<input type = "hidden" name = "qty ['. $ GetColorTitle [' uniqueID ']. class = "qtyC" /> ` ?